# PHP - assign value of function to class constant

Tags: php

In PHP when you define a class level constant as in:

```
const MY_CONSTANT = 'hello constant';
```

Why can't you initialize this value with a function such as

```
const MY_FILEPATH = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/heres-my-file.php';
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This has already been discussed in depth here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960323/why-dont-php-attributes-allow-functions the answer is long :) Anyway, it's definitely not possible, you may want to leave it at that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In short: The constants are replaced while parsing, but functions are executed while interpreting. The parser simply cannot know to what it should set the value of the content.

Comment: Hi, thanks.  Ok that kind of makes sense then. Whats the best practice for doing this kind of thing as it must happen quite a lot - where a constant value is requried but it is defined from a function call or something.

Answer (score 2):

Constants are immutable. Therefore, if functions could change the value of a constant it wouldn't be a constant.

Comment: Yes but i am not trying to change the value of a constant, instead i am trying to initialise it with the value of a function.

Comment: I understand what you mean. However, if the function could initialize a constant, theoretically it would be able to change its value. Because the constant must be initialized in the class (if it was declared in the class too).

Comment: "if the function could initialize a constant, theoretically it would be able to change its value". This doesnt make much sense to me. If a constant is initialized, its a constant. If its not initialized, it does not exists. There is never a change.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant "if the function could (set) a constant value ..". Because the value of a constant must be set when declared and only once.

Comment: your answer is not helpful. This pattern is allowed in Java for `final` variables that are evaluated exactly once. Evidently it is not allowed in PHP. But the reason why has nothing to do with functions changing the value of a constant; there's no inherent reason why a variable could not be assigned once from the value of a function. If the programmer uses in this instance a function that does not return identical results for function calls with the same arguments... well, that's a poor choice on the part of the programmer to use for a definition of a `constant`. Otherwise, why not?