# init value array for a object

Tags: php

init value array for a object.

```
class test{
   private $H_headers = array("A","B K ".chr(128),"C","D");
                                                 //Why I can not init this value?
   ...
  }
}
```

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - syntax error, unexpected ','
    - syntax error, unexpected '.', 
     expecting ')'
```

But normally I can:

```
$H_headers = array("A","B K ".chr(128),"C","D");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't PHP attributes allow functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960323/why-dont-php-attributes-allow-functions)

Comment: yes, I see but it not easy to understand what they answer ?But for me is simpler than.and  look at this I still can not solve my problems.

Comment: In short: You cannot use functions there. Just dont use functions there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pekka already provided one solution, but the downside is, that the class must implement a constructor just for assigning a value. Because the function you want to call is not that special (just get a character for a specific ascii code) you can also use this

```
class test{
   private $H_headers = array("A","B K \x80","C","D");//Why I can not init this value more here
  }
}
```

`80` is `128` in hexadecimal and the `\x` tells php, that you want this as a character.

Update:
Something to read about it :)

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: This is a fair point and probably fits the OP's situation better, +1.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do what you want in the class definition. The duplicate link discusses why this was designed this way.

The best workaround is  to do the assignment in the constructor:

```
class test {  

  private $H_headers = null;

  function __construct()
    { $this->H_headers = array("A","B K ".chr(128),"C","D");  } 

}
```