# PHP Class $_SERVER Variable a Property

Tags: php, class, properties

I'm developing a class and I have this structure:

```
class userInfo {
    public $interval        = 60;
    public $av_langs        = null;

    public $ui_ip           = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    public $ui_user_agent   = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    public $ui_lang         = null;
    public $ui_country      = null;

    // non-relevant code removed
}
```

But when executing the script I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in
>   D:\web\www\poll\get_user_info\get_user_info.php on line 12

When I changed the 2 $_SERVER vars to simple strings the error disappeared.

So what's the problem with $_SERVER in declaring class properties?

Thanks

Comment: The above are not variable assignments, but class property *declarations*. As such they cannot hold expressions. Not allowed there. You must use constants or do it in the constructor. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this code as a guide:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->ui_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $this->ui_user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Property can be declared only with value, not expression.
You can create __construct() method, where you can initialize properties in any way.

Comment: ok can you give me a simple example? I'm not very used to classes.

Comment: I made simple set_ip() and get_ip() functions and put 

$ui->set_ip($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$ui->get_ip();

and it works, but why not declaring it directly?

Comment: @medk because `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is expression, and expressions are not allowed in that scope (because any expression can be fetched only in runtime). __construct() is "magic" method, where you can initialize all your properties in any way. [Read more in manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Answer (score 3):

> So what's the problem with $_SERVER in declaring class properties?

You can't preset class properties with variables nor with function calls.

Here is some in-depth discussion on why: [Why don't PHP attributes allow functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960323/why-dont-php-attributes-allow-functions)

The bottom line however is, it's simply not possible.